# Confused on basic percentage.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$A$ is $60$% of $B$.

$B$ is $30$% of $C$.

> What percentage of $C$ is $A?$

Honestly this question totally confused me.

This is what I tried so far

$A$ is $60$% of $B$.

$A={60\over 100}B$

$B$ is $30$% of $C$.

$B={30\over  100}C$

---

${A\over C}={18\over 100}=18$%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing fine.  Now you have to use those two equations to relate $A$ and $C$.

HINT:  Substitute the value of B from the second equation into the first equation.

Can you state the result as a percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Using the value of second equation you can manage the answer which is most probably 18%